# Rails adding phantom whitespace above yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, layout, yield

This is killing me.

Application layout:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body topmargin="0"><%= yield %></body>
</html>
```

Home:

```
<div id="content">...</div>
```

Yet in the rendered page, across all browsers, there's a line of preformatted whitespace that pushes the content off the top of the window.

[image: WHITESPACE! Y U NO GO AWAY?]

Where is this coming from?

**Resolved**

Invalid HTML markup (`li` directly within a `div`) caused all browsers to add a gap at the top.  Strange!

Comment: What do you see if you look at the actual source?  As opposed to chrome's interpretation of it.

Comment: Interestingly, the source shows the content butted directly against the body tag `<body  topmargin="0"><div id="content">`

Comment: @RSG This blank line is probably just due to how Chrome's inspector is displaying it, then (the inspector will put each element on its own line to show the structure clearer). If your actual page display is screwed up, are you sure it isn't related to a CSS issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have an open html tag somewhere, just run your html through a validator and see if it catches any.

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: It was this.  I had `<li>` directly inside `<div>`, this introduced whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for finding the needle in the haystack!

Comment: Glad i was of help!! Now remember to always validate your html, older browsers will thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Correct your tag:

```
<%= yield %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was just a typo in the posting though.

Comment: and also with `<body>` tag, the tag should be closed properly.

Answer (score 2):

I thing you looking in wrong layout, because you have

```
<body><%= yield %><body>
```

but in the screenshot you have

```
<body topmargin="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it stumped me for a few hours.  I eventually noticed that the pages causing issues had a file type of "UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM)"  I just converted the file to remove this and it worked perfectly.